# How to run multiple batches when streaming from HDFS source?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a dataset like this `val df = spark.readStream.schema(s).parquet ("/path/to/file").where("Foo > 0").groupBy("bar").agg(expr("sum(Foo)"))`. The dataset has over 1 million records and the Parquet file contains 1 partition.

I start the stream by `df.writeStream.outputMode("update").format("console").start`.

Then Spark processes the entire file at once. But I expect that Spark some how "splits" the file and processes each split at a time while updating the result, just like the words count example updating result when I input a new word.

I tried adding `trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("x seconds"))` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then Spark processes the entire file at once. But I expect that Spark some how "splits" the file and processes each split at a time while updating the result, just like the words count example updating result when I input a new word.

That's how Spark Structured Streaming works with files. It processes them at once and never considers them again. It does "split" the file into parts (well, that should be in the hands of the storage, e.g. HDFS, not Spark itself actually), but it does so under the covers.

Please note that once a file is processed the file will never be processed again.

> I tried adding `trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("x seconds"))` but it didn't work.

Well, it did, but not how you wanted.

> **DataStreamWriter.trigger** sets the trigger for the stream query. The default value is ProcessingTime(0) and it will run the query as fast as possible.

Consult the scaladoc of [DataStreamWriter](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter).